# Ajax Loader Not Showing in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, loader

Although this has been discussed many times here in Stackoverflow, I couldn't get the loader gif to display in Google Chrome. In Firefox 3.6, the code I have below works just fine for displaying the little gif whenever I make an ajax call but the same code won't display anything if working with Google Chrome. Since our customer uses Chrome I have to make sure it is compatible.

Here is the jQuery code which is inside the onLoad event:

```
var loader = $('<div id="ajax-loader" class="ui-corner-all"><span></span></div>')
                .appendTo("body")
                .hide().ajaxStart(function() {
        var relativeToDocument = false;
        var parent = loader.parent();
        loader
                    .css("top", (relativeToDocument ? $(window).scrollTop() : 0)
                                + (parent.innerHeight() / 2)
                                - (loader.height() / 2))
                    .css("left", (relativeToDocument ? $(window).scrollLeft() + parent.offset().left : 0)
                                 + (parent.innerWidth() / 2)
                                 - (loader.width() / 2))
                    .show();
                })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
                loader.hide();
    });
```

Does anyone know why it isn't displayed for chrome?

EDIT: Adding some of my markup below;

The css for the gif is here:

```
#ajax-loader { position: absolute; padding: 10px; }
#ajax-loader span { background-image: url("../images/ajax-loader.gif"); width: 32px; height: 32px; display: block; }
```

The [page](http://jsfiddle.net/rzXSx/) is here. Of course it looks bad because I haven't added the css files and other things. Plus, this is a MVC application so you won't have any data to load.

Comment: Are you certain there's a <body> tag on your page to append to?  Is there also a closing </body> tag?  Also, the jQuery.ajaxStart and jQuery.ajaxStop methods only work for jQuery ajax calls (I believe) so this will only show up when you use jQuery.ajax (or .get/.post) and not custom ajax code or ajax through another JS library.  I tested your code out on a very simple page and it works in Chrome for me.

Comment: Well, like I mentioned above, it works pretty well for firefox. And yes, there's a body tag to append to in my form. The loader gif won't show up only for google chrome.

Comment: Could you add a jsFiddle or jsbin link that contains the broken page and code?

Comment: I've added it to my main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have some cross-browser issues I think about markup first, then code. I'd suggest to run a validation (http://validator.w3.org/) and see what you find.. Also, if possible, attach part of your html markup so we can test it as well - nothing like team debugging :)

wait, I just noticed the div is empty, that means you must have used css to position the gif (background image?), please attach the relevant styling as well

edit:

1. OK, I took the liberty to fix the
   errors jslint pointed out (even
   meaningless semicolons) and [forked
   it to a new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzXSx/3/). Notice how
   i stacked most of the js in 1 place.
2. Also, chrome should have a built-in
   "debugger" like firebug in firefox,
   maybe you can see the errors that
   comes up there as well.
3. Lastly, I know this is probably
   annoying to hear, but I really do
   suggest seperating styling, js code
   markup completely for better
   readability, and please try [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: I've added it to my main post.

Comment: thanks, If I some js scripts to the javascript portion of jsfiddle and run jslint i found some errors:

Problem at line 53 character 129: Missing semicolon.

var url = '/Warehouses/GetRackBusyPercent?zoneId=-x-&warehouseId=-y-'...

Problem at line 104 character 38: Missing semicolon.
$myWindow.css('overflow', 'auto')
Problem at line 135 character 188: Missing semicolon.
header = String.format("<h3>Na posição <b>{0}</b> existe{2} {...

Comment: Well, that's strange because I ran jslint too and it said that my code is valid.

Comment: Oh yes, it doesn't use semicolon, it's not needed. It's a long story but that is not the problem.

Comment: I'd love to hear it :), btw did you try the w3c validator?

Comment: I think we're getting nowhere just looking at your code, let's try some changes instead.. Can you try to load the same div inside any of your .load/.ajax functions instead of .ajaxStart?

     p.s: you can remove the loader inside the callback for the .load instead of .ajaxStop

Comment: tutuDajuju, I showed you the markup that the browser returned, using firebug for that matter. Of course the javascript and the css are in separate files throughout the application but this is a MVC application and I wouldn't be posting the code of all the files that made up that markup I posted.

Comment: After tidying up my code as tutuDajuju suggested me, I was able to get my loader showing up in Chrome. For that reason, he is the winner of this bounty. Thanks for you help mate.

Comment: A small 1 for me, a huge win for W3C standard :).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but just in case someone is having the same challenge, all I had to do working on an MVC 5 application, was to install the Nuget package in Visual Studio: 'NWebsec.Mvc' and the application ran just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but your abuse of whitespace is atrocious even for a jQuery developer. I don't know why jQuery developers feel the need to chain every call they make on one line.

```
var top, left;
top = relativeToDocument ? $(window).scrollTop() : 0;
top += parent.innerHeight()/2 - loader.height()/2;
loader.css("top", top);
left = relativeToDocument ? $(window).scrollLeft() + parent.offset().left : 0;
left += parent.innerWidth()/2 - loader.width()/2;
loader.css("left", left);
loader.show();
```

Holy cow look at that! It now looks like a real programming language! Now you can actually maybe try logging or stepping through your problem with a debugger without wanting to blow your brains out.

Also it might also just be the case that Chrome is just faster so that the loading icon does appear, it just happens too quickly to notice. I doubt it, but sometimes when Chrome and Firefox differ it's been because Chrome was faster or loaded script resources quicker or something along those lines.

Comment: The problem isn't about the speed of Chrome and Firefox. I'm making ajax calls with jquery in my form which take about 9-10 seconds to finish so the gif is pretty noticeable in Firefox.

Comment: Well why not try adding the icon outside of the ajax request and see if that works. And if it does then you know it's not the code that actually adds the gif that's broken. If it is, debug it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the first part of your code, you're creating a variable and you're using it in the ajaxStart function body declared in the variable. It looks like this might cause issues with the execution context and scope chains.

```
var loader = $('<div id="ajax-loader" class="ui-corner-all"><span></span></div>')
            .appendTo("body")
            .hide().ajaxStart(function() {
    var relativeToDocument = false;
    var parent = loader.parent();
    ...
```

Have you tried separating the definition of loader from the ajaxStart function? For example:

```
var loader = $('<div id="ajax-loader" class="ui-corner-all"><span></span></div>')
            .appendTo("body").hide();
loader.ajaxStart(function() {
    var relativeToDocument = false;
    var parent = loader.parent();
    ...
```