# Ajax loader is not showing up in chrome

Tags: html, ajax, dom, ajax-request

I am using an ajax loader (like a please-wait .gif image) image for the ajax calls. Before some days it was working perfectly and showing in chrome.

I didn't see any problem with the image or we don't change it. It is showing correctly in IE, Mozilla and in other browsers but I am not getting why it is not showing in chrome.

I had looked at [Ajax Loader Not Showing in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086191/ajax-loader-not-showing-in-google-chrome) but not getting any help.

The html mark-up is

```
<div id="divajaxProgress" class="progressouter" style="display: none;">
     <div class="ProgressInner">
        <img alt="" title="Please wait..." src="../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
     </div>
</div>
```

`divajaxProgress` will show up when an ajax call will be there, a simple example is page load. Here is the functions

```
function HideProgress() {                
  $("#divajaxProgress").hide();
}

function ShowProgress() {        
  if ($('#divajaxProgress').is(':visible') == false) {
    $("#divajaxProgress").show();
  }
}
```

You can see the image [here](http://www.hrgp.biz/Images/ajax-loader.gif)

Please suggest me what is the problem here.

Comment: Show js code, please.

Comment: where is ur ajax call?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh there are several ajax call on my page, the common one is document.ready function.

Comment: @Atber It's a simple js function, I modified the question with js code. Please have a look.

Comment: I had updated the question with some error code from google, please have a look

Answer (score 6):

Did you recently change to use synchronous Ajax call?

async: false

If so, I have seen this issue with animation not updating.  Most browsers don't get the control back during the synchronous ajax call and does not update the image.  However somehow Firefox was updating the image.

Comment: no, I don't. But my point is the image is working before some days and now its not showing up in Google chrome only.

Comment: There isn't any problem with ajax calls. Please try to open the image in chrome (from the link I provided) and have a look with inspect element you will find the image there but it is not showing in chrome. If you open it in IE and Mozilla you can see the image instead.

Answer (score 2):

try this instead. Tested on chrome!!!

```
function HideProgress(){
     $('#divajaxProgress').css('display','none');
}

 function ShowProgress() {        

    if($('#divajaxProgress').css('display') == "none"){
        $("#divajaxProgress").show();
    }
 }


    $.ajax({
        url: 'url here',

        type: "post",

        beforeSend: function () {
             ShowProgress();
        },

        error: function(){
           HideProgress();
        },

        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            HideProgress();
        }
    })
```

This might not be the structure of your ajax but make sure you call the `ShowProgress()` in the **beforeSend** and call the `HideProgress()` after the **success** callback or **error** callback.

Comment: no it's not working either... and please see my reply in above answer.

Comment: well, i guess the problem is not the show or hide function. The problem should be in your ajax call. Could you attach the ajax code function you are using? Your question is not specific to the context of your problem.

Comment: There isn't any problem with ajax calls. Please try to open the image in chrome (from the link I provided) and have a look with inspect element you will find the image there but it is not showing in chrome. If you open it in IE and Mozilla you can see the image instead.

Comment: Visit www.preloaders.net and get a png version of your loader. gif versions of loader i believe i gradually going through deprecation. preloaders site generators often suggest png versions of loaders. good luck

Comment: You can use a converter like http://www.zamzar.com/ to convert the gif to png just in case u're using a custom gif you want to keep. this is my best bro. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like following. Using Jquery you can change the display style of the blocks. This should work in cross browser too.

```
function HideProgress() {                
  $("#divajaxProgress").css({ display: "none" });
}

function ShowProgress() {                
  $("#divajaxProgress").css({ display: "inline" });
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: not its not working. Another point is I just did change the type of image from .gif to .png and it is showing up there but not as animated i.e. the animation with not working from the .png image.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is corrupted. It is not showed up in Chrome at all.

If you open an image in a text editor you will see a html form appended:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1"><title>
    Untitled Page
</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="ViewFile.aspx?FileId=2473" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNzgzNDMwNTMzZGQ=" />
</div>

    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems like it was appended by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with:** change or add to `async: true,` in ajax section like as following.it may work..

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'url here',

        type: "post",
        async: true,  //for synchronize browser & server side.

        beforeSend: function () {
             ShowProgress();
        },

        error: function(){
           HideProgress();
        },

        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            HideProgress();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead hidding loader in success or error.
Hide it under complete state of ajax call

```js
$.ajax({
        url: 'url here',
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
             ShowProgress();
        },
       complete: function () {
           HideProgress();
       },
       success: function (result) {
            alert(result);       
       },
       error: function(err){
          //Show error 
          alert(err);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. and got this solution

Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

if you are using Property  "async: false" in ajax call then please try this solution.

```
        $("div.spanner").show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveAnswer")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        if (result.Status) {                            
                            bool = true;

                        } else {
                            alert(result.Message);
                        }
                    },
                error: function (result) {
                    $("div.spanner").hide();
                    }
            });
        }, 10);
```